# href attribute of Link in IONIC project is generating an error

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

[VS Code sample how is highlited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP10n.png)

As is shown in the image when I use a <Link href={'/(modal)/filter'} asChild> the href attribute is highlited indicating that is not assignable to type 'StaticRoutes | RelativePathString | `http${string}`'

Please give some ideas how to solve this issue Im new to react and ionic